# Ignore self signed certificate errors c# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, ssl-certificate

I want to ignore self signed certificate errors both in REST full services and SOAP services.
In my research i found doing it through using the following code

`httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, 
   cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };` this didn't work for me

and another one is using `ServicePointManager`, But i can't access `ServicePointManager` though i referenced `system.Net`
Please provide me a code to ignore SSL errors in detail.

Comment: What is your framework version?

Comment: As uwp doesn't target framework, i can't tell you the exact framework i'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I should point out that please be careful to ignore Self Certificate Errors since there may be some dangers to do this.

You can try to use the [HttpBaseProtocolFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.ignorableservercertificateerrors#Windows_Web_Http_Filters_HttpBaseProtocolFilter_IgnorableServerCertificateErrors) Property to do that. You can get the details about how to use it from the following blog and sample:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/10/17/how-to-ignore-self-signed-certificate-errors-in-windows-store-apps-8-1/

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-ignore-Self-Signed-e50b89b6

In addition, since version 16299, UWP app support .NET Standard 2.0, you can target your UWP app on or after version 16299 to try to use the [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netstandard-2.0) class.